# Vuejs, components and cache

Tags: vue.js, caching

i was looking for a way to 'cache' some API fetched data in my application, and find out it can simply be done with localStorage (or even sessionsStorage)

While it works fine, i'm looking for a way to have all the cached data in one localStorage entry (in JSON)

The problem is i can't figure out how to build the JSON tree without overriding previous item. Let me explain :

On my dashboard, I have two components, one that load categories, the other loading last articles. Each component uses a different endpoint.

this is how i set cache (for categories) :

```
methods: {
    async getCategories() {

      let response = await fetch('https://carreblanc.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/fr/categories.json', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: zendeskHeaders,
      })

      if (response.status === 200) {
        let data = await response.json();
        this.categories = data.categories

        // Build cache
        let cacheData = []
        cacheData.push(data)
        sessionStorage.setItem('zhc_db_cat_cache', JSON.stringify(cacheData))
      }
      else {
        console.log("Something went wrong (" + response.status + ")");
        return Promise.reject(response);
      }
    },
    setUrl(url) {
      return decodeURI(url.substring(url.indexOf('-') + 1))
    }
  },
```

for articles :

```
methods: {
    async getArticles() {

      let response = await fetch('https://carreblanc.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/fr/articles.json', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: zendeskHeaders,
      })

      if (response.status === 200) {
        let data = await response.json();
        this.articles = data.articles
        
        // Build cache
        let cacheData = []
        cacheData.push(data)
        sessionStorage.setItem('zhc_db_art_cache', JSON.stringify(cacheData));
      }
      else {
        console.log("Something went wrong (" + response.status + ")");
        return Promise.reject(response);
      }
    },
    setUrl(url) {
      return decodeURI(url.substring(url.indexOf('-') + 1))
    }
  },
```

this results in two entries in the sessionStorage :

[image]
[image]

I want only one item, let's say 'zhc_cache', in which i can update data while components load..

for example : dashboard: {
categories: {
......
},
articles: {
......
}
}

I think there's something going on with the async function, but i can't figure it out,

any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand it correctly, you just want one JSON object with categories AND data?
In that case, i think you should create an object ("zn_cache"), in which you add categories and articles

```
//If you want to keep both functions, just set vuejs data variables (categories and articles) and affect them the data you fetched from the api
this.categories = data.categories
this.articles = data.articles
```

Then you can create a global object with both (check the syntax I'm not 100% sure)

```
let dashboard = { 'categories' : this.categories, 'articles' : this.articles}
```

Then you can store this bad boy

Comment: hi antoinehenrio,
you're right, but the thing is that it is two component, and depending on their loading time, first one override the others

Comment: this is the dashboard template

`
  template: 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-12"> 
        <Categories />
      </div>
      <div class="col col-12"> 
        <Recents />
      </div>
    </div>
`

Comment: Have you tried using props?
I don't know exactly how your code is working, but you should call both methods in the Dashboard components (in the created() method), update the variables with the results and then store everything in the cache.
Then, your Categories and Articles components should have props linked to the variables which contain the data.

Comment: So the components will render when the data is retrieved and yet you won't override the data
Please let me know if I'm not clear enough ;)

Comment: I got the idea ;)
i'm updating the code right now, and will come back to tell you

thanks for your help

Comment: No worries bro let me know if that suits your needs ;)

Answer (score 0):

@antoinehenrio

works like a charm ;)

here is the dashboard now

```
const zendeskConfig = {
  categoriesEndpoint: 'https://carreblanc.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/fr/categories.json',
  articlesEndpoint: 'https://carreblanc.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/fr/articles.json'
};

import Categories from '/skin/frontend/carreblanc/revamp/js/zendesk/hc/components/dashboard/categories.js'
import Recents from '/skin/frontend/carreblanc/revamp/js/zendesk/hc/components/dashboard/recent-activity.js'

export default {
  components: {
    Categories,
    Recents
  },
  data() {
    return {
      categories: [],
      articles: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      Promise.all([
        fetch(zendeskConfig.categoriesEndpoint).then(res => res.ok && res.json() || Promise.reject(res)),
        fetch(zendeskConfig.articlesEndpoint).then(res => res.ok && res.json() || Promise.reject(res))
      ]).then(([resCategories, resArticles]) => {
        this.categories = resCategories.categories
        this.articles = resArticles.articles
        let cacheData = { dashboard: { 'categories' : this.categories, 'articles' : this.articles} }
        sessionStorage.setItem('zhc_db_cache', JSON.stringify(cacheData))
      })
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getData()
  },
  template: `
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-12"> 
        <Categories :categories=this.categories />
      </div>
      <div class="col col-12"> 
        <Recents :articles=this.articles />
      </div>
    </div>
    `
}
```

and the result :

[image]

I have to reconfigure the other views, but it should be easy now

Thanks again !